# How to get comma seperated list of column names where column values are equal to "True"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to write a SQL Server query which can select all comma seperated column list where column values for that row is "True". 
This is what my table and here c1, c2, c3 and c4 are column

```
ID c1  c2  c3  c4
1  Yes No  Yes No    
2  Yes Yes No  No    
3  No  Yes No  No    
4  Yes No  No  No    
5  Yes No  Yes No    
6  Yes No  No  No    
7  No  No  Yes No
```

My expected result is:

```
1  c1, c3    
2  c1, c2    
3  c2    
4  c1    
5  c1, c3    
6  c1    
7  c3
```

I tried a lot but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using conditional concatenation:

```
select id,
       stuff( (case when c1 = 'Yes' then ', c1' else '' end) +
              (case when c2 = 'Yes' then ', c2' else '' end) +
              (case when c3 = 'Yes' then ', c3' else '' end) +
              (case when c4 = 'Yes' then ', c4' else '' end),
              1, 2, ''
             )
from t;
```